# Pandas creating new dataframe based on old dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I am trying to take data from two existing data frames and create a third based on the values in the first two. I need to create a new data frame based on the value of Column 3 in DF_1 (Zone). If the data reads "All Zones", the new DF needs to contain a record for each possible store zone combination.

DF_1 | SKU with Price Zone

[SKU with Price Zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gWhq0.png)

DF_2 | Stores and Price Zones

[Store and Price Zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfPAq.png)

*Desired* DF 3

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvUDk.png)

I have tried many different approaches but cannot nail down the process of multiplying out rows based on another dataframe and still maintaining the original data. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, it makes it harder for us to have to click on it and go back. Just copy and paste it here and format it as code.

Comment: Please post _running_ example code. We want tested answers and the best way to get there is running examples.

Answer (score 0):

You should first work a bit on DF_1, so that it has only one row per zone. The rows with "All Zones" should be replicated into as many rows as zones there are, and row 2 should be replicated into three rows, one per zone. That would be a better data format.

(In order to easily convert "All Zones" to one row per zone, you could create a copy of DF_2, remove the "Store" column and add a column with the SKU value (do this twice, for rows 1 and 3 in DF_1)).

Once you have that, you can easily [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) DF_1 and DF_2 using the zone column as join key.